# Using include disable's add-to-cart button in products pages in opencart 3.0.2

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

In the product.twig file, i need to include another twig file , the file gets linked and working, but that disables the add-to-cart button in every product page

```
    {{ header }}
    <div id="product-product" class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
                <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="row">{{ column_left }}     

    {{ include('default/template/extension/total/demo_file.twig')  }}

   {% if column_left and column_right %}
            {% set class = 'col-sm-6' %}
        {% elseif column_left or column_right %}
            {% set class = 'col-md-9 col-sm-12' %}
        {% else %}
            {% set class = 'col-sm-12' %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Event is bind on the add to cart button. The even code lies in the same file , so make sure the id of the button is same as previous button you are replacing.

Other way could be updating the event bind function jQuery selector.